# Помиловать, и точка

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении: «Помиловать и точка» нужна запятая перед «и»?

Comment: А вы сами как думаете? У нас тут сложное предложение или простое?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Мне кажется, что сложное.

Comment: думаю, есть две основы...

Comment: Конечно же, две основы, и значит ставим запятую. Но давайте пофантазируем, как можно из этого предложения сделать одну основу? Пуская без сохранения точного смысла. У меня есть ответ..

Comment: «Помиловать бесповоротно»))... Не знаю...)

Comment: Ага, только так: "Помиловать, и бесповоротно". Есть еще вариант.

Comment: валяйте еще один)....

Comment: Помиловать или точка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"И точка", "и всё'. Перед "и" здесь необходима запятая или тире. Без знака препинания написание будет ошибочным.

Answer (score 6):

*Помиловать, и точка*.

Запятая сюда просится в любом случае, назовём мы это присоединительной конструкцией или междометным предложением. Это фразеологическое сочетание имеет значение "и разговор окончен", "и конец спорам", "и хватит разговоров!" и ещё много синонимов, по смыслу равно целому предложению, выражающему чувство, категоричное требование.

Comment: А разве это не восклицание?

Answer (score 3):

В разных синтаксических конструкциях возможны варианты, причем интонационно они четко различаются (простое предложение или предложении с обособлением):

(1) ***ПомИловать, // и тОчка.***  (2) ***Помиловать и тОчка.***

Выбор зависит от того, как предложение **вписывается** в контекст и как вы его будете **произносить.** При постановке запятой первое слово подчеркнуто ударением, а при отсутствии запятой ударение переходит на второе слово. Первый вариант более эмоционален, а во втором интонация спокойная, без пафоса.

В Нацкорпусе запятая **ставится чаще, но не всегда.**  Это фразеологическое сочетание со значением «окончательно, без возражений»,  поэтому ему можно придать как **соединительное, так и присоединительное значение.**

Примеры

**(1)  Запятая не ставится**

Но те, в белых халатах, были неумолимы ― не положено и точка. [Василь Быков. Болото (2001)]
Вывод для меня ― реалист: класс усечён и точка.

Опять, и опять, и опять: скандинавы и точка.

Нельзя демонтировать обелиск «Городу-герою Ленинграду». Нельзя и точка. Без комментариев.

(2)  Запятая ставится

Я не советую тебе ее брать, и точка.

Все, как у меня, и только так! И точка!!!!

Сказал не отдам, и точка!

Долой доказательства! Аксиома ― и точка.

(3) **Варианты оформления одного текста:**

А я вам сто раз говорила: три дня ― и точка. [Дина Рубина. Камера наезжает (1993-1994)]

А я ей говорила ― три дня и точка! [Дина Рубина. Камера наезжает (1993-1994)]

Comment: А что за синтаксическая конструкция-то получается в итоге? Вы так и не сказали. Простое предложение с присоединительным "да и"? Присоединения с союзом "да и" вроде бы всегда обособляются, нет? Или может быть, у вас конструкция однородного ряда?

Comment: (1) Союз И может быть соединительным или присоединительным – это не вызывает сомнения. (2) Присоединительная конструкция может быть любой (слово, словосочетание, предложение), запятая ставится.  Всё это есть у Розенталя.  (3) Соединительный союз И  (при отсутствии запятой)  должен соединять однородные конструкции, но вы можете вложить в сочетание «и точка» любой смысл и придать ему любую форму, чтобы получились однородные отношения с первой частью.

Comment: То есть вы считаете, что у нас однородные отношения? Отлично. Тогда почему бы не поменять их местами, ведь ничего не должно измениться. Давайте попробуем: И точка, помиловать. Что же вроде получилось, нет? Но тогда все равно надо ставить запятую между однородными членами. Понимаете?

Comment: Понимаю –  вы мыслите в рамках вами же составленных схем. Читайте Кустову (стр. 107, Типы отношений между однородными членами). Члены ряда могут быть полностью равноправными или дифференцированными (наречиями и др.), тогда их уже не переставишь: Этот маяк более высокий и поэтому более заметный.  Также обратите внимание на похожее сочетание «и всё такое».  Оно обычно не обособляется, хотя обособление встречается: «Пишет: люблю и все такое. Всё, конечно, понятно, талант и все такое. Уперлись: здесь деды жили, здесь молодость прошла, и всё такое». Тоже будете синтаксис определять?

Comment: Дифференцирование однородных членов - всего лишь добавочное явление к обычным однородным членам. Сравните: Этот маяк более высокий и более заметный. Пишет: люблю и аналогичное люблю. Любое дифференцирование можно опустить, ввиду его добавочности (да смысл теряется, но грамматика остается). У нас нечего опускать. Есть всего два слова соединенных союзом и. Но вам нельзя отказать в какой-то оригинального рода, извращенной смекалке. Я без иронии, респект!

Comment: Вообще-то это называется не извращенностью ума (когда он что-то огибает), а расширением сознания.