# Нужен ещё один пауэрбанк, и точка

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно?

> Нужен ещё один пауэрбанк, и точка.

> Нужен ещё один пауэрбанк и точка.

> Нужен ещё один пауэрбанк — и точка.

Comment: @Sharon Пишу здесь, чтобы комментарии (их уже 19) не ушли в чат. Поставлю Максиму плюс, если ответ будет дополнен. Приводится цитата филолога о трёх вариантах, а получаем два. А в самой статье говорится и о четвёртом.

Comment: Леопольд, ответ я изменил. Как вам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение *и точка* может выделяться как запятой, так и тире:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото из [этого сайта](https://aif-ru.turbopages.org/aif.ru/s/society/education/nuzhna_li_zapyataya_vo_fraze_vkusno_i_tochka).

Получаем такие варианты:

***Нужен ещë один пауэрбанк, и точка***;

***Нужен ещë один пауэрбанк — и точка***.

Если пауза недолгая, ставим запятую; если подольше — тире.

Comment: Пройдя по вашей ссылке на Викисловарь, можно увидеть: "Встречаются также варианты написания и произношения: *павербанк, пауэрбанк*. На второй из них тоже есть [статья в Викисловаре](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/пауэрбанк). Вот ещё Грамота отвечает: "Рекомендуем писать: *пауэрбанк* (по аналогии с написанием *пауэрлифтинг*)".

Comment: Оц, извиняюсь. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: Максим, а как выбрать?  "Из двух выбирают одно, такая уж правда простая..."

Comment: Если более сильная интонация, тире. Если нет, запятую.

Comment: Кстати, а как же ещё два варианта? С точкой и без всякого знака. "Ваша" филолог Марина Королёва пишет: "Иногда оно вообще становится отдельным предложением: «А я хочу. И точка!»". А далее идут её главные, на мой взгляд, слова: «Знаки препинания, как мне кажется, появляются в тех случаях, когда "И точка” произносится с присоединительной интонацией». // В статье также говорится: "Но встречаются и случаи, когда никакого знака нет", и приводится пример. А заглянув в Нацкорпус, можно увидеть многочисленные случаи необособления.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец Какой у нас ИНТЕРЕСНЫЙ стал форум! Когда вопросов много, это не так уж плохо...) Александр, а как вы сами объясните варианты?  И когда же допускается отсутствие знака? Кроме тех случаев, когда это просто неграмотное написание.

Comment: @Максим А какая сильная интонация? Можно, к примеру, восклицательный знак добавить. Ну, это если кто-нибудь не понимает... // А к кому обращена такая речь, как вы думаете? Может, это тоже "самые главные слова"?  // Присоединительная интонация, а что это? Понимать можно по разному. Мне кажется, это все-таки тесно связанные части предложения.  // Нет, верить нельзя никому))

Comment: @Sharon Объяснил я, конечно... Я имел в вилу, пауза большая.

Comment: А когда нужна большая пауза? Ключевое слово – когда. Вы просто написали Y  вместо X.  А на мои вопросы не ответили.

Comment: @Sharon Цитирую вас: "В разных синтаксических конструкциях возможны варианты, причем интонационно они четко различаются (простое предложение или предложении с обособлением)". Ну и далее по тексту [вашего **замечательного** ответа](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463994/Помиловать-и-точка/464000#464000).

Comment: Да уж, как вы это нашли...   За два года я мало изменилась, такая же извращенность ума (которая предлагается в качестве расширения сознания). Но теперь мне не хватает КОНТЕКСТУАЛЬНОСТИ.   Новая ведь идея! Контекстуальность в русском языке  https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/kontekstualnost-v-russkom-yazyke

Comment: Современная научная парадигма языкознания, ставит в центр внимания соотношение между языком и действительностью. В этой ситуации все более актуальной становится проблема точного и полного взаимного понимания участников КОММУНИКАЦИИ.                                                                                                 
Автор ставит перед собой задачу выявить те типовые проявления русского языка, когда возникают ТРУДНОСТИ при общении. Рассматривается многозначность русских слов и грамматических форм, а также те УСЛОВИЯ, в которых достигается или не достигается однозначное понимание.

Comment: @Sharon Это уже какую паузу автор поставит.

Comment: Это уж смотря по ситуации и по участникам коммуникативного общения. Например: Вы с приятелем говорите или со своим папой? Если с папой, то категоричность ни к чему (денег не даст). И как долго вы убеждаете вашего приятеля – тоже важно.  Отсюда  вывод: дайте КОНТЕКСТ,  и у меня не будет вопросов.

Comment: @Sharon Контекст "должен" давать спрашивающий, за него придумывать – себе дороже. Без контекста мы или говорим о вариантах, зависящих от задумки автора (от безпаузности, паузности разной длительности и от ударений на разных словах), или вообще ничего не говорим.

Comment: @Александр Стрелец  Александр, не могу с вами, к сожалению,  согласиться. Автор вопроса затрудняется определить зависимость текста от ситуации, а вам ведь совсем не сложно придумать одно-два предложения для контекста.  Тогда и объяснять долго не придется. (Мы с вами как-то уж обсуждали это.) Ведь конкретика всегда лучше общих формулировок. А вернее, дополняет эти формулировки.

Comment: @Sharon Лео уже опытный пользователь и сам прекрасно знает о контекстуальности, вариативности и интонации. // Но плюс за вопрос я всё равно поставил.

Comment: Да с чего вы взяли, мы его не так хорошо знаем. У него хорошее чувство языка, поэтому он может изобразить ситуации. Но я думаю, что ему нужна теория для пояснения этой конкретики. И не будем забывать: мы отвечаем не только автору, но и всем участникам форума, а также нашим  гостям.  (Тогда я тоже поставлю плюс.)

Comment: Тогда уж и Максиму надо поставить плюс. Без его ответа никто бы и не заметил вопрос.  Хотя мы иногда его критикуем, но его присутствие на форуме  также положительно сказывается на активности отвечающих.  Другими словами, определяет ситуацию, когда начинается дискуссия.